# Remover BOM de archivos UTF-8

Tags: php, json, utf-8

Recibo algunos archivos JSON codificados en UTF-8, pero estos archivos vienen con BOM (no puedo cambiarlo ni tengo control sobre ello).
El problema es que estos archivos fallan al ser decodificados usando `json_decode()` (ver https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php#112631).

He probado:

```
$jsoncontent = file_get_contents("archivo_recibido.json");
$jsoncontent = str_replace("\xEF\xBB\xBF",'',$json_content);
```

Existe alguna manera mas estandar o mas segura de remover dicho BOM en el codigo PHP antes de procesar el archivo sin que afecte la codificacion del archivo? (pensando en *multi-byte* y otros posibles escenarios)

Comment: Puedes usar `trim($jsoncontent, "\\xef\\xbb\\xbf");` pero no veo diferencia en cuanto a estandarización o seguridad. De entrada [str_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php)  tiene esta nota: _Esta función es segura binariamente._

Comment: Hablando de multy-byte strings no existe una funcion `mb_str_replace() `como si los hay para otras funciones de strings, pero segun leo, `str_replace` tambien es segura en multi-byte strings (por ello no existe una funcion mb_* para ello)

Comment: ¡Exacto! No deberías tener problema usando ese código.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta este codigo:

```
function remove_bom($text)
{
    //Empaqueta los argumentos dados a una cadena binaria según el formato dado por format
    $bom = pack('H*','EFBBBF');
    //Remplazo el string pasado.
    $text = preg_replace("/^$bom/", '', $text);
    return $text;
}

$jsoncontent = file_get_contents("archivo_recibido.json");
$jsoncontent = remove_bom($jsoncontent);
```

Comment: Recuerda que las respuestas con código sin explicación no son bien recibidas. Agrega información acerca de las mejoras que implica usar tu propuesta y cómo funciona.

Comment: La solucion intenta reemplaza la primera secuencia `\xEF\xBB\xBF`, pero necesita usar el modificador `/u` en la expresion regular para que sea multi-byte safe. `"/^$bom/u"` https://www.php.net/manual/es/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php